# A question on consistency proof for propositional calculus as in Kleene's "Introduction to metamathematics".

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm self studying Kleene's IM. On page 129/130 there's a proof of (simple) consistency of the propositional calculus, i.e. for no formula $A$, both $\vdash A$ and $\vdash \lnot A$.

Then, a few lines after the proof he states: "This consistency proof, of course, does not hold good for the addition of another group of postulates even should that group by itself be consistent."

Why?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a hypothetical proof system $S$ which proves just one formula: $\vdash_S p \land \neg p$, and nothing else. This proof system is consistent: Nothing tells us that it has a rule such as conjunction elimination from which one could derive two contradictory formulas. The proof system is obviously not sound w.r.t. the semantics of classical propositional logic, but it is not inconsistent.

For the propositional calculus, we have $\vdash_P \neg (p \land \neg p)$, and we also established that the calculus is consistent.

So $P$ and $S$ in isolation are consistent, but their unification $P + S$ is not, because we have $\vdash_{P + S} p \land \neg p$ and $\vdash_{P + S} \neg (p \land \neg p)$.